# (Python) which is more efficient to split a string multiple separators? 1) Using multiple replace method then using split 2) using regular Expressions

Tags: python, replace, split, python-re

Example:

**(Case 1)**

#first using replace method to replace different type of separator to single type then using split method

```
text = "python is, an easy;language; to, learn."
text_one_delimiter = text.replace("# ", ", ").replace("% ", ", ").replace("; ", ", ").replace("- ", ", ")

print(text_one_delimiter.split(", "))
```

**(case 2)**

#Using regular expression for splitting using multiple separators

```
import re

text = "python is# an% easy;language- to, learn."
print(re.split('; |, |# |% |- ', text))
```

Comment: Did you benchmark it? Are you aware of ``str.translate``?

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, This method is far better.

Comment: Even though, i will appreciate if someone can answer my original question

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal - "more efficient" in what dimension? Code readability? Performance? Please specify. When performance I tend to MisterMiyagi and to would just measure it.

Comment: in terms of Performance

Answer (score 1):

[timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module is useful for speed comparison of code snippet. It might be used following way:

```
import timeit
case1 = '''text = "python is, an easy;language; to, learn."
text_one_delimiter = text.replace("# ", ", ").replace("% ", ", ").replace("; ", ", ").replace("- ", ", ")
text_one_delimiter.split(", ")'''
case2_setup = "import re"
case2 = '''text = "python is# an% easy;language- to, learn."
re.split('; |, |# |% |- ', text)'''
print(timeit.timeit(case1))
print(timeit.timeit(case2,case2_setup))
```

Output (will depend on your machine):

```
1.1250261999999793
2.2901268999999616
```

Note that I excluded `print`s from examined code and make `import re` setup, as otherwise it would import it without need several time.
Conclusion is that *in this particular case* method with multiple `.replace`s is faster than `re.split`.

*(tested in Python 3.7.3)*